# sql trigger to update columns of different table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi I want to implement a trigger, I have two Tables:

**Insertion on Table1**

```
*Table1**
Name     File
a        abc
b        efg

**Table2**
Name     File
a        abc
b        efg
```

**Updation**

```
**Table1**
Name     File
a        file1
b        file2


**Table2**
Name     File
a        abc,file1
b        efg,file2
```

I want to write a trigger on Table1 which will copy Column 'Name' 'File' values to Table2 on every insert and on updation of Column File for a particular Name value in Table1, it will update the 'File' column value as comma separated form in the Table2.

I am able to create the insertion trigger successfully but the following trigger for the update, updates all the rows common in the two tables :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2 AFTER UPDATE ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Table2 INNER JOIN 
           upload 
           ON (Table2.Name = Table1.Name)
         SET Table2.a_file = CONCAT(Table2.a_file, ","),
             Table2.a_file = CONCAT(Table2.a_file, "Table1.a_file") ;
```

Also the CONCAT() function is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this update trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2 AFTER UPDATE ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Table2 SET a_file = CONCAT(a_file, ",", NEW.a_file) WHERE Name = NEW.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use NEW to get updated values
for example

```
NEW.a_file --not table1.a_file (for trigger on table1)
```

Comment: This should be a comment. You have to rep to comment, so comment!